# How can we load 49 000 records using Report viewer?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a stored procedure that return 49 000 records. 
I need to display all of them in a report viewer.

However each time I run the report, I get following error message:

An error occurred during local report processing.
An error has occurred during report processing.
Exception of type 'System.outOfMemoryException' was thrown.

Is there any ways I could display and also provide a button to export the report?

Thanks.

Comment: Close your connection after you have used and also make null your dataset and datareader after used.try it

Comment: Use paging so the report only load enough data for each page. You might need to modify the SP to support paging

Comment: The question is who will look at a report containing 49000 records? Makes  no business sense.

Comment: Found the solution: [link](https://yugalpandya.wordpress.com/2013/09/30/custom-paging-user-control-for-large-amount-of-data-in-gridview/)  Custom paging user control for Large amount of data in Gridview